# Javascript function not called for some reason

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, webautomation

I am making a script to automate the procedure of purchasing supreme Items in order to checkout an item before a competitor does. In my script I have already made it so it scans the page for a keyword and then picks that item with a specified size, the only problem I have is that the `selectItem()` Function is never called at line 451. When you try to run the script it simply does nothing, it was completely functional before I turned the main code into the `selectItem()` function.

If anyone knows why please tell me, I know some of the code is very messy but it's in very early stages at the moment and will be sorted once it is functional. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is good to share your whole code, but please do not paste commented out codes as they made your post messy. Not easy for those who want to help and try to get your version of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectItem()` is an `async` function and should be prefixed with `await` everytime you call it; for example:

```js
if(rawTxt1.indexOf(kw) != -1){
      await selectItem(rawTxt1, srcTxt1)
```